Switching to Dark Theme on Stack Overflow pages
I just switched to a new computer (to macOS from MS Windows).  I have
poor eyesight and depend on dark theme to be able to read my
screen.  Stack Overflow pages are currently very difficult for
me to read.  A web search informs me that there is a dark theme
preference I can set in Stack Overflow, but I've not been able
to find it.  The search result said:

Access: Log into your Stack Overflow account, go to your profile
settings, and select "Dark" under the theme preference option.

On my Stack Overflow home page if I search for "profile" I get
nothing useful.
I can't find "Profile Settings" on the Stack Overflow site.  On
the Stack Overflow corporate home page there's a menu at the top
left that disappears when the mouse moves off of the menu button
into the menu itself.  This using Chrome on MacOS.
How do I get to the profile settings and enable dark theme?

Click on the icon with your avatar and reputation, below the big avatar should be a bubble called "Settings". First option, there. BTW, questions about SE itself should be asked on [meta]. I voted to close.
